# How to run Test Suites sequentially in ScalaTest / SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

How to run Test Suites sequentially in ScalaTest / SBT?

For example if I have this test suites A, B and C I want to make sure that the tests of A will be run 1st then the ones of B then the ones of C.

Is there in configuration that I can make in Scalatest or SBT?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

try using parallelExecution in Test := false

Comment: Hello Raj. Thank you for your answer. For my understanding, this command is rather to run sequentially the tests of the same Test Suite.

Comment: To expand on @Farah response, the original poster wanted to run some tests in parallel when they are in a different test suite, but tests in the same suite be run sequentially.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation http://doc.scalatest.org/1.7/org/scalatest/Suite.html

You need to create your own Test Suite like the following:

FirstTest.scala

```
import org.scalatest.{DoNotDiscover, FunSuite}

@DoNotDiscover
class FirstTest extends FunSuite {

  test("first test"){
    assert(1 == 1)
  }

}
```

SecondTest.scala

```
import org.scalatest.{DoNotDiscover, FunSuite}

@DoNotDiscover
class SecondTest extends FunSuite{

  test("second test"){
    assert(2 == 2)
  }
}
```

MainTest.scala

```
import org.scalatest.Suites
class MainTest extends Suites (new FirstTest,new SecondTest)
```

Now, if you run sbt test it's work properly.

Notes: the property @DoNotDiscover is mandatory. this avoid unexpected behavior like execution of FirstTest and SecondTest after the execution of the MainSuite that are already executed the two test suites.

I hope it was helpful

Comment: I think this is the best way, and is also independent of which build tool (sbt, gradle, ...) you're using.

Answer (score 1):

As *raj mehra* said, the solution is to configure to run the tests not in parallel.

`Test / parallelExecution := false`

Former `parallelExecution in Test := false` is deprecated.

Here is the Documentation that explains it: [SBT Parallel Execution](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Parallel-Execution.html#Parallel+Execution)

From it:

> As before, `parallelExecution in Test` controls whether tests are mapped to separate tasks.